# pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PIL

Tags: python, linux, django

I am trying to use the [reviewcode](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.5/admin/installation/linux/) of python/django for a git repo.
while installing the

> easy_install ReviewBoard

I got the following error

> Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed
>   with exit status 1.

this error occurred while installing the PIL dependency. I installed it manually using

> pip install PIL

which installed successfully

but on creating the site like :

> sudo rb-site install /var/www/reviewboard

but Now getting the annoying error:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PIL

any clue, How this problem can be resolved ?

**Update**

> ```
> PIL SETUP SUMMARY
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> version      Pillow 2.3.0
> platform     linux2 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49)
>              [GCC 4.8.1]
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> *** TKINTER support not available
> --- JPEG support available
> --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
> *** LIBTIFF support not available
> --- FREETYPE2 support available
> *** LITTLECMS2 support not available
> *** WEBP support not available
> *** WEBPMUX support not available
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
> To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
> library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
> setup.py script.
>
> To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
>
> changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilprint.py from 644 to 755
> changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilconvert.py from 644 to 755
> changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilfont.py from 644 to 755
> changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pilfile.py from 644 to 755
> changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/pildriver.py from 644 to 755
> changing mode of /home/naveen/ENV/ly-subs/bin/pilprint.py to 755
> changing mode of /home/naveen/ENV/ly-subs/bin/pilconvert.py to 755
> changing mode of /home/naveen/ENV/ly-subs/bin/pilfont.py to 755
> changing mode of /home/naveen/ENV/ly-subs/bin/pilfile.py to 755
> changing mode of /home/naveen/ENV/ly-subs/bin/pildriver.py to 755
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Python 1.6 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/):

> Pillow is now the preferred image manipulation library to use with Django. PIL is pending deprecation (support to be removed in Django 1.8). To upgrade, you should first uninstall PIL, then install Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

Comment: A little more description could be useful

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.